# Extracting the converged? bool of scipy.optimize.newton() result

Tags: python, optimization, convergence

I'm trying to find the <strike>minimum</strike> root of a function using scipy.optimize.newton(). The function I'm using is very complicated, and as a result I decided to have a set number of iterations and to keep the final answer even if the precision asked is not respected. As such, I would like to know when convergence happened and when it didn't, in one single bool variable.

The problem I'm running in is that newton() returns a 2 dimensional array with the root result as the first value, and the second value is an object with several values, of which I can't seem to extract the converged one.

I tried to look only at the second value of the newton return function. This is my code:

```
from scipy.optimize import newton

def function(x):
    return x**2-1

def fprime(x):
    return 2*x

x0=5

test = newton(function, x0, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=5, fprime2=None, x1=None, rtol=0.0, full_output=True, disp=False)


print(test[1])
```

Which gives

```
      converged: False
           flag: 'convergence error'
 function_calls: 7
     iterations: 5
           root: 1.0103336911991998
```

and what I would like is just one variable with 'False' in it (for this example)

Comment: `scipy.optimize.newton` finds the root of a function, that is,  `x0` where `f(x0) = 0`. But you said you wanted a minimum of the function. Could you clarify this?

Comment: sorry, yes, I'm trying to minimise a function by finding the root of a related function. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your way of calling `scipy.optimize.newton`, `newton` returns a 2-element tuple, and the first element is the root, the second is a `RootResults` object. If you want to get the `converged` attribute of the `RootResults` object, you just need to
use dot notation, `some_obj.attribute`.

```py
root, r = newton(function, x0, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=5, fprime2=None, x1=None, rtol=0.0, full_output=True, disp=False)
converged_flag = r.converged
print(converged_flag)
```